# Getting the content in body of a webpage using python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scan various websites using python. The following code works fine for me.

```
import urllib
import re
htmlfile =urllib.urlopen("http://google.com")
htmltext=htmlfile.read()
regex='<title>(.+?)</title>'
pattern=re.compile(regex)
title= re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
print title
```

To get the body content, I changed it as follows:

```
import urllib
import re
htmlfile =urllib.urlopen("http://google.com")
htmltext=htmlfile.read()
regex='<body>(.+?)</body>'
pattern=re.compile(regex)
title= re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
print title
```

The above code is giving me an empty box brackets. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Please help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally it's a bad idea to attempt to [parse HTML with regular expressions](http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/).

The excellent [beautiful soup library](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) makes what you're trying to do trivial.

```
import bs4

html = '''
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div></div>
</body>
'''

print(bs4.BeautifulSoup(html).find('body'))
```

Python also has an [HTML parser in its standard library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html), which is basically a less feature rich version of the beautiful soup parser.

If you're still insistent on using regex, this should work.

```
import re
print(re.findall('<body>(.*?)</body>', html, re.DOTALL))
```

Also this may sound dumb, but make sure there're actually body tags in the `htmltext` string.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I don't have much knowledge of beautifulsoup but what you suggested worked great.

Comment: works great. But how do you get rid off the `<body>` and </body>` tags then ?

Comment: @clemlaflemme to remove the outer `body` tags, use: `bs4.BeautifulSoup(html,features="html.parser").find('body').decode_contents()`

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question, actually if you go through `HTMLtext`, you won't find two body tags. But I definitely recommend you to take the Beautiful Soup route as @rectangletangle mentions